# what is the typescript signature of function makeObject(key,value){ return {[key]:value}; }?

Tags: typescript

```
//fake code;there shoud be type annotations
function makeObject(key,value){ 
   return {[key]:value}; 
}
const obj=makeObject("name","Tom");
```

#### what do I want

I want the typescript compiler to infer obj has type {"name":string}, but I have no idea what the signature of "makeObject" should be.

#### what I have tried

I have figure out how to make tsc recognize "name as a string literal type.

```
function makeKey<Key extends keyof {[k:string]:any}>(key:Key):Key{
    return key;
}
const key=makeKey("name")//tsc infer "key" has type "name" not string
```

#### my question

is this possible with current typescirpt(3.9+)? if it is then how?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the key type `K` and the value type `V`, where `K` is constrained to `PropertyKey` (which is basically `string` or `number` or `symbol`).

The only snag is that the compiler will view `{ [key]: value }` as being a type with an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html?#indexable-types), due to [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).  That's presumably not what you want... you're not trying to put values of type `V` at *every possible* key, just the one of type `K`.

We can work around that by [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that it is of the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `{[P in K]: V}`, equivalent to `Record<K, V>`, meaning "an object with keys of type `K` and values of type `V`":

```
function makeObject<K extends PropertyKey, V>(key: K, value: V) {
   return { [key]: value } as { [P in K]: V };
}
const obj = makeObject("name", "Tom"); // {name: string}
```

Looks like what you want.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmB5ARgK02gB4BpRTADykzABMBnRABQCc4AHTVqAT1My8ANIgBqAPgAUWXgC5EpEQDdUAGxCZ5ogJSIA3gFgAUIlOtMUEKyR7EAbRkBdeSvWZEAX0Somtu80QYJFJnMU8AbmMPYwgEBihEOAJEAF4UDBwCIihJACIwVGRMXJFcgBU4ZFztcMQAejr9AqL5eNYggHMvIA)

Comment: That's exactly what i want. I didn't know there is a builtin "PropertyKey" , thanks a lot.

Comment: You’re welcome; please consider accepting the answer if it meets your needs!